# How to extract features using date range within a month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, feature-extraction

I would like to extract features from a datetime column for a day/date for example between day 1 to 10, the output is stored under a column called

> early_month
>   as 1 or 0 otherwise.

The following question I posted earlier gave me a solution using indexer_between_time in order to use time ranges.

[How to extract features using time range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876151/how-to-extract-features-using-time-range)

I am using the following code to extract days of the month from date.

```
df["date_of_month"] = df["purchase_date"].dt.day
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create some sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but if you are trying to create a column that contains a 1 if the day is between 1 and 10, or 0 otherwise, it's very simple:

```
df['early_month'] = df['date_of_month'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <= 10 else 0)

df['mid_month'] = df['date_of_month'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 11 and x <= 20 else 0)
```

As a python beginner, if you would rather avoid lambda functions, you could achieve the same result by creating a function and then applying it as so:

```
def create_date_features(day, min_day, max_day):
    if day >= min_day and day <= max_day:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['early_month'] = df['date_of_month'].apply(create_date_features, min_day=1, max_day=10)
df['mid_month'] = df['date_of_month'].apply(create_date_features, min_day=11, max_day=20)
```

Comment: Hi. This is working but how would I define it to specify a specific range like from 11 - 20 for mid_month? Please tell me if I'm not clear. I'm a beginner at Python.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need convert boolean mask to integers - `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='17D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'purchase_date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

m2 = df["purchase_date"].dt.day <= 10

df['early_month'] = m2.astype(int)
print (df)
  purchase_date  a  early_month
0    2017-04-03  0            1
1    2017-04-20  1            0
2    2017-05-07  2            1
3    2017-05-24  3            0
4    2017-06-10  4            1
5    2017-06-27  5            0
6    2017-07-14  6            0
7    2017-07-31  7            0
8    2017-08-17  8            0
9    2017-09-03  9            1
```

Detail:

```
print (df["purchase_date"].dt.day <= 10)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: purchase_date, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this one:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'time':['11.07.2018','12.07.2018','13.07.2018','14.07.2018','15.07.2018']})
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%d.%m.%Y')

df[df.time>datetime(2018,7,13)] #if you need filter for date
df[df.time>datetime(2018,7,13).day] #if you need filter for day
```